# Tensor product over a tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose $M$ is an $R$-module and $N$ is an $S$-module. Then $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$ is an $R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} S$-module given by $r\otimes s\cdot m\otimes n:= rm\otimes sn$. My question is whether the following claim is valid or not:

> $(M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N)\otimes_{R\otimes_\mathbb{Z}S} \mathbb{Z}\cong (M\otimes_{R} \mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}\otimes_S N)$ as $R\otimes_\mathbb{Z}S$-modules.

EDIT: $R=\mathbb{Z} G$ and $S=\mathbb{Z}H$ for groups $G$ and $H$, and I am viewing $\mathbb{Z}$ as both an $R$ and an $S$ module by actions induced by $Gx=x$ and $Hx=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.

If so, would one cook up the maps in both directions and show they are inverse to one another, or are there isomorphism theorems that we can take advantage of for tensors over tensors?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a trivial action? If the action annihilates everything then the result is true because the tensor products are all trivial.

Comment: Does Proposition 11.13 (or, if the numbering changes, just search for "straightforward (repeated) application of the universal property") in http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/algebra/HopfComb-sols.pdf help you? Arguably I leave the proof to the reader, but I think the more symmetric form of it (one of your $\mathbb Z$'s is secretly a $\mathbb Z \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z$) should clear up some things.

Comment: @MattSamuel By trivial action I meant $r\cdot x=x$ for all $r\in R$ and $z\in \mathbb{Z}$. I've edited this for clarity.

Comment: That doesn't define a module structure. Try it with $\mathbb Z$. $1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1=2\neq (1+1)\cdot 1=1$.

Comment: @MattSamuel I see, I guess what I mean is if $R=\mathbb{Z} G$, the group ring, and $G$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$. Does that remedy the situation?

Comment: No. In order for the action to be defined $\mathbb Z$ would have to be a vector space over the field, which it clearly isn't.

Comment: @MattSamuel Apologies, I hadn't thought about this carefully enough before asking. I hopefully have added an additional hypothesis to make this sensible. Thanks for clearing this part up for me.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you, this answers my question; I'll try to verify the proposition.

Comment: The link I cited above has rotten. A more up-to-date version is Proposition 12.88.1 in [Darij Grinberg, Victor Reiner, *Hopf Algebras in Combinatorics*, arXiv:1409.8356v5, version with solutions](https://arxiv.org/src/1409.8356v5/anc/HopfComb-v73-with-solutions.pdf).